# Postgresql how to concatenate strings but only when values are different?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to create a view that is aggregating my column "country". My table looks like this:

```
project_ref | country
----------------------
1           | Italy
1           | Italy
2           | France
2           | Italy
```

Currently, I run the following query:

```
CREATE VIEW a AS
SELECT project_ref,
string_agg(country, ', ') AS country
FROM b GROUP BY project_ref ORDER BY project_num ASC;
```

and I get the following table as a result:

```
project_ref | country
----------------------------
1           | Italy, Italy
2           | France, Italy
```

Is there a way to remove the duplicated values "Italy, Italy" in order to have "Italy" mentioned only once?

I would like to have the following table instead:

```
project_ref | country
---------------------------
1           | Italy
2           | France, Italy
```

But I can't find the way to get there... Any ideas?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.5 version.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `distinct` inside `string_agg`:

```
string_agg(distinct country, ', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to remove the duplicate records and create an array with them. If you want to store the country collections as text separated by comma, use the function `ARRAY_TO_STRING` as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW a AS
SELECT project_ref, 
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT country 
                      FROM b q2 
                      WHERE q1.project_ref = q2.project_ref),',') AS country
FROM b q1 
GROUP BY project_ref
```

And here is your view without the duplicates:

```
db=# SELECT * FROM a;
 project_ref |    country 
-------------+-----------------
           1 | Italy
           2 | France,Italy
(2 Zeilen)
```

An advantage of this approach is that you can run your `DISTINCT` with more than one column, by means of using `DISTINCT ON (colmun1, column2, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks! It works great for removing duplicates but it duplicates my number of records when the values are different. So I will have France, Italy twice.